# How do I interpret a log-plot that looks exponential?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

When looking at an x,y plot such that the y-axis is the logarithm of $f(x)$, generally the plot looks like a line. How am I supposed to interpret a plot that still looks exponential after applying a log on the output?

Comment: This is caller super-exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation means that the function is growing faster than exponentially. You might consider taking logarithms again.

This image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number) shows that the logarithm of the number of digits of the largest known prime $p$ is increasing linearly with time. But the number of digits of $p$  is the logarithm of $p$, so if you just graphed the logarithm of $p$ over time it would grow exponentially.

[image]